# Why are type hints for variables not handled as type hints for function parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, typechecking, python-typing

When writing a function in Python with type hints like this:

```
def foo(token: Token=None):
  pass
```

It translates to this type hint: `Optional[Token]`. With optional, a `None` value is accepted too.

---

When writing the same type hint for a class field, it doesn't behave the same:

```
class bar:
  foo: Token = None
```

Here type hint checkers like the integrated one in PyCharm reports:

> Expected type 'Token', got None instead.

**My questions are:**

- Why is in the parameter case the hint and `None` *implicitly* combined to `Optional[...]`?
- Why do fields behave differently, while having the same syntax?

I use PyCharm 2019.3.

Comment: I didn't realize that you could just use `None` instead of `Optional[Token]`.  Awesome, now is it just an implementation detail of Intellij products or all type checkers?

Comment: Handled by what? What third-party tool are you using?

Comment: @JBirdVegas I couldn't find an answer to that question too. I olny found [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/429) with lots of formats to improve handling of `Optional[...]`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's PyCharm 2019.3 (as written in my question).

Comment: `token=None` was a common idiom for parameters with default values long before type  hinting came along. Using class attributes to signify instance attributes was not; it only came into being *after* type hints were introduced, meaning there was no historical usage to accommodate.

Comment: "It translates to this type hint: Optional[Token]" *what* does? The annotations don't. Previously, it was acceptable to omit `Optional` or `Union[whatever, None]`, and static type checkers were suppose to infer that, but now it is required to sue `Optional` according to the spec. So basically, you are asking, "why is PyCharm's integerated static analysis inconsistent", which I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the best place for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is in the parameter case the hint and None implicitly combined to Optional[...]

This is how PyCharm's static type checker infers the type of arguments when their default values that are set to `None`. It infers the type to become `Optional[type]` of what you declared. This inference rule is applied differently for variable declarations outside of signatures.

> Why do fields behave differently, while having the same syntax?

From what we are given to understand from the below sources this was a syntax detail choice aimed at making signatures more concise although introducing an implicit rule.

The way PyCharm's static type checker is implemented aligns with historical PEP 484 changes. The current revision states:

> [Union types - PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types)
>
> A past version of this PEP allowed type checkers to assume an optional type when the default value is None, as in this code:
>
> ```py
> def handle_employee(e: Employee = None): ...
> ```
>
> This would have been treated as equivalent to:
>
> ```py
> def handle_employee(e: Optional[Employee] = None) -> None: ...
> ```
>
> **This is no longer the recommended behavior. Type checkers should move towards requiring the optional type to be made explicit.**

Looking at the revision history ["PEP 484: Do not require type checkers to treat a None default special…"](https://github.com/python/peps/commit/0630155b47c27f25e66267d247f0205aa953f113) the reasons are given in [Pull request #689](https://github.com/python/peps/pull/689) linking back to [typing issue #275](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/275).

I altered your code, because `Token` was undefined, to:

```py
def foo(token: int = None) -> None:
  pass

class bar:
  foo: int = None
```

Using the mypy static type checker with [default configurations](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#none-and-optional-handling) the warnings are issued as expected:

```
error: Incompatible default for argument "token" (default has type "None", argument has type "int")
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "int")
```

I didn't find any [PyCharm inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html) having a configurable option for this.